# Spring Security integration with Project Reactor

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, project-reactor

I have an application that relies on the authentication bound to the request thread (e.g. when calling external REST services the identity is sticked into an outgoing HTTP header transparently by a request interceptor on the RestTemplate).

I am in the process of learning and applying reactive patterns in this application using Project Reactor and started with making my REST api calls reactive. These are using the `Schedulers.elastic()` pool and lead to loosing the Spring Security Context. Even if I switched to using the InheritableThreadLocal context holder strategy the elastic pool would mix things up.

I am seeking for advice from people who have more experience in this topic about the best and most transparent pattern I could apply in this case. I did not manage to find any really appealing solution for this problem yet.

Is there any extension to Reactor or Spring Security that addresses this inconvenience? Is there any extension point in Project Reactor that I could leverage?

Comment: See https://spring.io/blog/2017/05/11/spring-security-5-0-0-m1 .

Comment: @M.Deinum I think that should be made into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reactive Support is the big theme for Spring Security 5. The [first milestone](https://spring.io/blog/2017/05/11/spring-security-5-0-0-m1) has been released not that long ago.

Comment: I scanned through the docs, but to be honest I did not find any references to solving this particular problem in it

Comment: could you show us your security config ? Are you using the reactive extension of Spring security ? ThreadLocal are difficult to use in Reactor as an alternative you can use Context and spring security reactive use ReactiveSecurityContextHolder